# Change the keybinding to exit (alt+f4)

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I'm currently using linux and pretty much every program with a GUI exits with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. Is there a way to change the default <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and put the following in it (assuming it's empty):

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+q"], "command": "exit" }
]
```

Save the file, and you should be all set.